# Find all possible combinations of even or odd numbers and perform mathematical operations on the result

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I am trying to find all possible combinations from taking one integer from each of three lists. The combinations must contain either all even or all odd integers.

I would then like to find the sum of the squares of the integers in each combination.

Finally I would like to create a dictionary that uses this value as the key and the combination it used as its stored value.

E.g. for the combination (1,3,1): the key would be the integer 11 (from the sum (1^2) + (3^2) + (1^2)) and the value stored would be (1,3,1)

My code so far:

```
lists = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]] 

combos = np.array([list(i) for i in np.array(np.meshgrid(*values)).T.reshape(-1,len(values))])
```

This takes three lists that each contain the integers 0-6

and uses an element from each list to create a combination of three integers

All possible combinations result: [0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,2,0], [1,0,0] ... [6,6,6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution.

**Code**

```
from itertools import product

lsts = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]] 

# Product generates all combinations of taking one from each list
combos = product(*lsts)

# We filter for the combinations with all odd or even
# using generator i.e. () but could have been a list i.e. []
valid = (c for c in combos if all(x%2==0 for x in c) or all(x%2==1 for x in c))

# Dictionary key is sum of the squares of c
d = {sum(map(lambda i : i * i, c)) : c for c in valid}

# Pretty Print result
import pprint
pprint.pprint(d)
```

**Output**

```
{0: (0, 0, 0),
 3: (1, 1, 1),
 4: (2, 0, 0),
 8: (2, 2, 0),
 11: (3, 1, 1),
 12: (2, 2, 2),
 16: (4, 0, 0),
 19: (3, 3, 1),
 20: (4, 2, 0),
 24: (4, 2, 2),
 27: (5, 1, 1),
 32: (4, 4, 0),
 35: (5, 3, 1),
 36: (6, 0, 0),
 40: (6, 2, 0),
 43: (5, 3, 3),
 44: (6, 2, 2),
 48: (4, 4, 4),
 51: (5, 5, 1),
 52: (6, 4, 0),
 56: (6, 4, 2),
 59: (5, 5, 3),
 68: (6, 4, 4),
 72: (6, 6, 0),
 75: (5, 5, 5),
 76: (6, 6, 2),
 88: (6, 6, 4),
 108: (6, 6, 6)}
```

Comment: I like it. And if a tuple needs to be changed to a list then it's a small change `d = {sum(map(lambda i : i * i, c)) : list(c) for c in valid}`

Comment: When I try and run this code it comes up with:
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @GotAFewQuestions--try this [link to my running version](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/PrudentOlivedrabTechnician) to see if there is any difference in the code you're running.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr

iter_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

evens = [
    [t[0], t[1], t[2]] 
    for t in list(cwr(iter_list, 3)) 
    if t[0] % 2 == 0 and t[1] % 2 == 0 and t[2] % 2 == 0
]

odds = [
    [t[0], t[1], t[2]] 
    for t in list(cwr(iter_list, 3))
    if t[0] % 2 != 0 and t[1] % 2 != 0 and t[2] % 2 != 0
]

evens_dict = {e[0] ** 2 + e[1] ** 2 + e[2] ** 2 : e for e in evens}

odds_dict = {o[0] ** 2 + o[1] ** 2 + o[2] ** 2 : o for o in odds}

final_dict = {}
final_dict.update(evens_dict)
final_dict.update(odds_dict)

final_dict

# if you need it sorted by keys, add this
#final_dict = {k : v for k, v in sorted(final_dict.items(), key = lambda v : v, reverse = False)}
#final_dict
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Law of Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) to enumerate the sequence of uniformly odd / even sums of integer squares directly.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
{
  sum(x ** 2 for x in xs): xs
  for xs in combinations_with_replacement(range(7), r=3)
  if sum(x ** 2 for x in xs) % 8 in {3, 4, 0}
}
```

[Youtube Channel "Mathologer" demonstrates a proof of the theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X63MWZIN3gM) which explains where the modulus and residue are found by breaking down "*the sum of 3 even/odd integer squares*" into coherent statements in modular arithmetic.

Comment: I love this solution.

Comment: what a beautiful solution!
Would you be able to add comments so that I can follow what exactly the code is doing, as I am not familiar with itertools.